# Mongoose model query failed for only some values

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

I try to do some simple query but it failed for some value. Bellow is code snippet

```html
// Create schema for query user
const userSchema = new Schema({
    id: String,
    phone: String,
    email: String,
    name: String,
    gender: String,
    birthday : String,
    name: String
    // location.name, id
})

// Create a model from that schema
const User = mongoose.model('user', userSchema);
// create a model's map to export
let userModel = {}

userModel.getUserInfoById = function (id, cb) {
    logger.debug("userModel.getUserInfoById: " + id)
    var query = {}; query["id"] =  id;
    logger.debug("query: " + JSON.stringify(query))
    User.findOne(query).exec(function (err, data) {
        logger.debug("query" + JSON.stringify(query) + " return: " + data)
        cb(err, data);
    });
}
```

**FAILED CASE LOG**

```
getUserInfoById req[object Object]
[2021-04-24T11:25:22.682] [DEBUG] models-user - userModel.getUserInfoById: 100000384124626
[2021-04-24T11:25:22.685] [DEBUG] models-user - query: {"id":"100000384124626"}
users.findOne {"id":"100000384124626"} { projection: {} }
[2021-04-24T11:25:22.719] [DEBUG] models-user - query{"id":"100000384124626"} return: null
```

**SUCCESS CASE LOG**

```
[2021-04-24T11:25:37.268] [DEBUG] models-user - userModel.getUserInfoById: 100001130533205
[2021-04-24T11:25:37.268] [DEBUG] models-user - query: {"id":"100001130533205"}
users.findOne {"id":"100001130533205"} { projection: {} }
[2021-04-24T11:25:37.298] [DEBUG] models-user - query{"id":"100001130533205"} return: {
  _id: 5ad6b600ec57c0a16a9e0cd2,
  id: '100001130533205',
  first_name: 'Nguyễn Võ',
  gender: 'male',
  location: {
    id: 'xxxxxxxxxxx',
    name: 'Thành phố Hồ Chí Minh, Hồ Chí Minh, Vietnam'
  },
  name: 'Nguyxxxxxxx',
  phone: '0000000000',
  username: 'nguyxxxxxxx',
  birthday: null,
  email: null
}
```

I checked by robo3T both query with: {"id":"100001130533205"} & {"id":"100000384124626"} return result.

Could anyone give me some suggestion?

Thank in advance,
Thinh

Comment: It sounds really weird, please go through your code and data from database and make sure everything is as expected.